# How can I produce a numpy-like documentation?

Tags: python, numpy, documentation, spyder, docstring

I'm working a lot with spyder and the object inspector, which I find pretty convenient as an instant help function. Some modules seem to profit very nicely from this function. For example a pretty basic numpy function (numpy.absolute) produces the following view in the object inspector:

[image: View of numpy.absolute function in object inspector]

I want to know, how I can write my own modules in such a way, that such a nice view is produced when I call my functions in spyder.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For your documentation to render as nicely as the numpy one, you need to follow the [NumpyDoc](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/HOWTO_DOCUMENT.rst.txt#id3) standard. Suppose you have a function called `func` with two arguments like this:

```
def func(arg1, arg2):
    return True
```

To add documentation to it you need to write a multiline string below its definition (called in the Python world *docstring*), like this

```
def func(arg1, arg2):
    """Summary line.

    Extended description of function.

    Parameters
    ----------
    arg1 : int
        Description of arg1
    arg2 : str
        Description of arg2

    Returns
    -------
    bool
        Description of return value

    Examples
    --------
    >>> func(1, "a")
    True
    """
    return True
```

What Spyder does is that it takes this plain text description, parses and renders it as html and finally shows it in the Object Inspector.

To see it you just need to call `func` somewhere else in your code and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> next to it, like this:

```
func<Ctrl+i>(1, "a")
```

This is also shown automatically when you write a left parenthesis next to `func`.

Comment: numpydoc is absolutely amazing and something that more projects should adopt

Comment: Absolutely! Almost all Python scientific projects use it but I think Spyder's Object Inspector encourages a much wider audience to adopt it in his/her code too.

Comment: You can view Quick Documentation (in PyCharm) by clicking on the function definition (without calling it elsewhere) and pressing CTRL+Q (on Windows). It may work similarly in other IDE or OS. Cheers!

Answer (score 9):

If you have your Python project (or file) already documented with an other style (as `reStructuredText` or `Epytext`) or not documented, you can generate/convert the docstrings into `NumpyDoc` style using [**Pyment**](https://github.com/dadadel/pyment):

```
pyment -o numpydoc /my/python/project
```

Note that the previous command, run after installed Pyment, will generate patches that should be applied to your code.

Once your project is documented using Numpydoc style, you can use the [Sphinx extension](https://github.com/numpy/numpydoc/) to generate your *nice* readable NumpyDoc style documentation!

Comment: How this answer hasn't been discovered and upvoted before? This is what I've been looking for, for a long time. Thanks!